# Does reliable outgoing SMTP require accepting incoming connections?

Tags: email

I'm running SMTP server for reliable delivery of mail (site notifications, user registration, password resets) but its outbound only, not receiving mail.  It has a PTR, matching host name, and SMTP banner that matches the PTR host name.

Recently its been brought to its knees, by SYN Flood.  I want to block all IPs except my web servers from connecting to it.  Will this cause any delivery problems?  Are there SPAM prevention solutions which require connecting back to the sender SMTP server to allow mail?

Comment: I've seen some anti-spam systems that send a autoreply back with a link to confirm that a human sent the mail.  Also, delayed delivery notifications, etc. would come back as a new connection and not just a response to a outgoing and established connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many large mail providers do not accept connections to port 25 on the IP addresses from which their e-mail originates, as do the mail systems I run for the company to which I primarily contract.  Deliverability does not appear to be adversely impacted.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know there is no standards requirement at all that mandates  the  outbound/sending smtp server to accept incoming connections.

Only the incoming mail servers, the ones where the MX records for your domain point to, need to accept incoming mail.

You need **a server** that accepts mail and bounces addressed to the domain name you use for sending but you are allowed to separate the sending and receiving  functionality to different servers, they don’t have to be one and the same.

Comment: That is reassuring, admittedly its not required by the standard, but some of those spam filters require things not in the standard like PTR record, SPF, Banner message, or two out of three of those, etc.   I suppose no spam prevention vendor will list out their heuristics explicitly because that makes it too easy to get around.  We will have to just give it a try and see if any users complain about missing messages!